# $Rank(A+B)\leq Rank(A)+Rank(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let there be $A,B$ matrices.

Let $C=A+B$

$Span(Col(C))\subseteq Span(Col(A))$ because C is a linear combination of A .
$Span(Col(C))\subseteq Span(Col(B))$ because C is a linear combination of B . 

Therefore $Span(Col(C))\subseteq Span(Col(A))+Span(Col(B))$ and $Rank(A+B)\leq Rank(A)+Rank(B)$

Comment: The first and second inclusions are not trues.

Comment: @Memming I did not understand the hint there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Span(Col(C))\subset Span(Col(A))+Span(Col(B)) $ then $Rank(C)\leq \dim(Span(Col(A))+Span(Col(B)))$, by using the inequality $\dim(F+G)\leq \dim F+\dim G$ we get $Rank(C)\leq \dim(Span(Col(A)))+\dim(Span(Col(B)))=Rank( A)+Rank(B)$

Answer (score 1):

Define $Lx = (Ax, Bx)$. Clearly $L$ is linear and
${\cal R} L \subset {\cal R} A \times {\cal R} B$ (this inclusion could be strict).

Hence $\dim {\cal R} L \le \dim ( {\cal R} A \times {\cal R} B ) = \dim {\cal R} A + \dim {\cal R} B$.

Now let $\phi(y) = y_1+y_2$, where $y = (y_1,y_2)$, again note that $\phi$ is linear. If $S$ is a subspace, it is easy to see that $\dim \phi(S) \le \dim S$ (this is true for any linear operator, not just $\phi$).

Letting $S = {\cal R} L$, and noting that $A+B = \phi \circ L$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to prove using Spans

Comment: Replace ${\cal R} A$ by $\operatorname{sp} (\operatorname{col} A)$. It is entirely equivalent.